# Diablo angel and demon name etymologies

Tags: diablo-iii

Is there any reasoning behind the names of the angels and demons in the Diablo series? I'm talking about characters like Azmodan, Tyrael, Malthael, etc.

Are they completely made up by the Diablo team or did they have some obscure source for the names. Do they actually mean anything?

Comment: The names you mention none of then have a known source from Wikipedia (aside form a Diablo page) but Diablo itself may be an allusion to the Spanish Devil, El Diablo. i would proably look up the demons on the [wikia](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Diablo_Wiki) and see if there is a trivial or etymology like what Diablo has under Trivia (mentioning the Spanish Devil)

Comment: Why is this downvoted? Is this kind of question not welcome here or should I have presented it differently?

Comment: @CameronBall not really, this is very heavily leaning toward "Developer Intent", which is off topic. We try to stick to issues that people might be having *in-game* or in trying to set up a game. But if you are asking "Why'd they name the characters the way they did?" - that's off-topic.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure this is "Developer Intent", but I'm also not sure if Arqade is the best fit for asking about the etymology of names...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Many of the details of Heaven and Hell in Diablo are heavily influenced by Judeo-Christian theology.

A lot of the names are either almost the same as, or at least share a similar naming structure to Judeo-Christian Angels and Demons.

Examples include,

- Azmodan ([Asmodai/Asmodeus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asmodeus)),
- Tyrael (very close to Turiel, one of [The Watchers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watcher_%28angel%29#Book_of_Enoch), who were tasked with watching over humanity, and became the parents of the [Nephilim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nephilim))
- Diablo (from the latin "diabolicus", and thus the Spanish word for Devil)
- [Lilith](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lilith) (literally the same name, Adam's "first wife", who left him to mate with [Samael](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samael#Judaism) the Angel of Death and give birth to a race of demons)

If you look through the below lists, you will notice a lot of similarities of structure:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_angels_in_theology

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_theological_demons